# Infinite while loop crashes WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, infinite

I'm still kind of new to C++ and WinAPI and I've come across an issue. I can't make use of an infinite while loop (while(true) in this case) in WinAPI but I can do exactly what I want to do in a console application without the crashing.

I'm trying to detect a key-press so I believe that I need this loop unless someone can provide other means of doing this.

```
while (true) {
  if (GetAsyncKeyState(MIDDLEMOUSEBUTTON)) {
    //my code here
  }
}
```

[image: Not responding]

Any help or advice with this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUI apps are event driven.  Your loop is preventing a message loop from processing new messages.  That is why your app is unresponsive.  You need a message loop, and you need your message handler to process `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP`, and/or `WM_CHAR` messages to handle key presses, `WM_(L|M|R)BUTTONDOWN` and/or `WM_(L|M|R)BUTTONUP` messages to handle mouse clicks, etc.